# Compose two Scala futures with callbacks, WITHOUT a third ExecutionContext

Tags: scala, future

I have two methods, let's call them `load()` and `init()`. Each one starts a computation in its own thread and returns a `Future` on its own execution context. The two computations are independent.

```
val loadContext = ExecutionContext.fromExecutor(...)
def load(): Future[Unit] = {
  Future
}

val initContext = ExecutionContext.fromExecutor(...)
def init(): Future[Unit] = {
  Future { ... }(initContext)
}
```

I want to call both of these from some third thread -- say it's from `main()` -- and perform some other computation when both are finished.

```
def onBothComplete(): Unit = ...
```

Now:

1. I don't care which completes first
2. I don't care what thread the other computation is performed on, except:
3. I don't want to block either thread waiting for the other;
4. I don't want to block the third (calling) thread; and
5. I don't want to have to start a fourth thread just to set the flag.

If I use for-comprehensions, I get something like:

```
val loading = load()
val initialization = initialize()

for {
  loaded <- loading
  initialized <- initialization
} yield { onBothComplete() }
```

and I get **Cannot find an implicit ExecutionContext.**

I take this to mean Scala wants a fourth thread to wait for the completion of both futures and set the flag, either an explicit new `ExecutionContext` or `ExecutionContext.Implicits.global`. So it would appear that for-comprehensions are out.

I thought I might be able to nest callbacks:

```
initialization.onComplete {
  case Success(_) =>
    loading.onComplete {
      case Success(_) => onBothComplete()
      case Failure(t) => log.error("Unable to load", t)
    }
  case Failure(t) => log.error("Unable to initialize", t)
}
```

Unfortunately `onComplete` also takes an implicit `ExecutionContext`, and I get the same error. (Also this is ugly, and loses the error message from `loading` if `initialization` fails.)

Is there any way to compose Scala Futures without blocking and without introducing another `ExecutionContext`? If not, I might have to just throw them over for Java 8 [CompletableFutures](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html) or <strike>Javaslang</strike> [Vavr Futures](http://www.vavr.io/vavr-docs/#_future), both of which have the ability to run callbacks on the thread that did the original work.

**Updated** to clarify that blocking either thread waiting for the other is also not acceptable.

**Updated again** to be less specific about the post-completion computation.

Comment: You should do `Future.firstCompletedOf(List(initialization, loading))` if you want to grab the result of the Future that completes first. The for-list-comprehension will wait for both futures to complete before performing the yield.

Comment: @pcting I do want to wait for both futures to complete before I perform some other computation. I don't want to block the current thread to do it.

Comment: If this is for the exact purpose of setting an AtomicBoolean to true, then you can instead have a Promise which when is completed indicates completion.
`promise.completeWith(initialization zip loading)`

Comment: @ViktorKlang It's not; that was just an example. I'll edit the question.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just reuse one of your own execution contexts? Not sure what your requirements for those are but if you use a single thread executor you could just reuse that one as the execution context for your comprehension and you won't get any new threads created:

```
implicit val loadContext = ExecutionContext.fromExecutor(Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor)
```

If you really can't reuse them you may consider this as the implicit execution context:

```
implicit val currentThreadExecutionContext = ExecutionContext.fromExecutor(
  (runnable: Runnable) => {
    runnable.run()
  })
```

Which will run futures on the current thread.  However, the Scala docs explicitly recommends against this as it introduces nondeterminism in which thread runs the `Future` (but as you stated, you don't care which thread it runs on so this may not matter).

See [Synchronous Execution Context](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/futures.html#synchronous-execution-context) for why this isn't advisable.

An example with that context:

```
val loadContext = ExecutionContext.fromExecutor(Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor)

def load(): Future[Unit] = {
  Future(println("loading thread " + Thread.currentThread().getName))(loadContext)
}

val initContext = ExecutionContext.fromExecutor(Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor)

def init(): Future[Unit] = {
  Future(println("init thread " + Thread.currentThread().getName))(initContext)
}

val doneFlag = new AtomicBoolean(false)

val loading = load()
val initialization = init()

implicit val currentThreadExecutionContext = ExecutionContext.fromExecutor(
  (runnable: Runnable) => {
    runnable.run()
  })

for {
  loaded <- loading
  initialized <- initialization
} yield {
  println("yield thread " + Thread.currentThread().getName)
  doneFlag.set(true)
}
```

prints:

```
loading thread pool-1-thread-1
init thread pool-2-thread-1
yield thread main
```

Though the `yield` line may print either `pool-1-thread-1` or `pool-2-thread-1` depending on the run.

Comment: As I said, I don't want to block the current thread, so SynchronousExecutionContext is out. If I explicitly choose one or the other of the existing ExecutionContexts, will it mean (assuming they're single-threaded) that that thread is blocked waiting for the other one? I don't want that either. (I'll update the question.)

Answer (score 1):

In Scala, a `Future` represents a piece of work to be executed async (i.e. concurrently to other units of work).  An `ExecutionContext` represent a pool of threads for executing `Future`s. In other words, `ExecutionContext` is the team of worker who performs the actual work.

For efficiency and scalability, it's better to have big team(s) (e.g. single `ExecutionContext` with 10 threads to execute 10 `Future`'s) rather than small teams (e.g. 5 `ExecutionContext` with 2 threads each to execute 10 `Future`'s).

In your case if you want to limit the number of threads to 2, you can:

```
def load()(implicit teamOfWorkers: ExecutionContext): Future[Unit] = {
  Future { ... } /* will use the teamOfWorkers implicitly */
}

def init()(implicit teamOfWorkers: ExecutionContext): Future[Unit] = {
  Future { ... } /* will use the teamOfWorkers implicitly */
}

implicit val bigTeamOfWorkers = ExecutionContext.fromExecutorService(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2))
/* All async works in the following will use 
   the same bigTeamOfWorkers implicitly and works will be shared by
   the 2 workers (i.e. thread) in the team  */
for {
  loaded <- loading
  initialized <- initialization
} yield doneFlag.set(true)
```

The **Cannot find an implicit ExecutionContext** error does not mean that Scala wants additional threads.  It only means that Scala wants a `ExecutionContext` to do the work.  And additional `ExecutionContext` does not necessarily implies additional 'thread', e.g. the following `ExecutionContext`, instead of creating new threads, will execute works in the current thread:

```
val currThreadExecutor = ExecutionContext.fromExecutor(new Executor {
  override def execute(command: Runnable): Unit = command.run()
})
```